# How to use React Router in Header, Footer and etc components instead of App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-component

Through the research that I have done on React Router, it seems every example that's online the React Router code is always stored in the `App.js` file.

What if you're wanting to use routers for links in the sidebar, header or footer?

Specifically, this is the example that I am learning from to implement React Router:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-react-router-include-router-hooks/

Desired result: Link a route to the Sitemap page with the component `attribute`.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Breadcrumbs from './components/Breadcrumbs';
import Recent from './components/Recent';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header/>
            <Breadcrumbs/>
            <Hero/>
            <Main/>
            <Recent/>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Footer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import SitemapPage from '../components/pages/SitemapPage';

const Footer = () => {
    return(
        <footer>
            <Container id="footer">
                <Row>
                    <Col className="col menu" xs="6" md="12">
                        <p className="text-right">
                            <BrowserRouter>
                                <Link to="/sitemap/">Sitemap</Link>
                                <a href="/">Terms</a>
                                <a href="/">Privacy</a>
                                <Route path="/sitemap/" component={SitemapPage} />
                            </BrowserRouter>
                        </p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </footer> 
    );
};

export default Footer;
```

**SitemapPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Breadcrumbs from '../Breadcrumbs';
import Footer from '../Footer';

const SitemapPage = () => {
    return(
        <div className="sitemap page">
            <Header />
            <Breadcrumbs />
            <p>Sitemap page</p>
            <Footer />
        </div> 
    );
};

export default SitemapPage;
```

It's imaginable that I am not the only developer that wants to set up routes with links throughout the website.

Without giving me the complete answer, could someone leave a comment with a good example that's similar to this?

Comment: Perhaps it's time to introduce props into the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your expectation, though here is some input:

What is in side your Router element will re-render when the route changes. So if you have your Router element in your Header element, when the route changes (user clicks the link), only your Header element will be re-rendered.

It's OK to have your Router element at the App element, and still you can put your link inside your header element.

Comment: There’s no need to downvote the post as I’m in the process of learning this. Thanks for your input, I’ll review it later this week.